# What was the first formal theory for asset selection/portfolio management?

Tags: portfolio-management, general

Just curious about the timeline and evolution of asset/portfolio selection theory from past to present

Comment: Please also see this article by Markowitz: The Early History of Portfolio Theory: 1600-1960, apparently Shakespeare was an expert in portfolio theory! link here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/4480178?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: @Magicisinthechain thank you! Exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 3):

In 1952, Markowitz published „Portfolio Selection“ introducing mean variance optimal portfolios („modern portfolio theory“) into finance and emphasising the effect of diversification. This work paved the way for Sharpe (1964) (and others) to develop the CAPM which marks the foundation of financial economics. Both obviously received the Nobel Prize. Beginning from there, asset pricing has developed many theories and models.

The Black Litterman (1992) model allows for incorporating your own views with regards to the expected returns of the assets. Another extension is the post modern portfolio theory from Rom and Ferguson (1994).